# Implementing user access to multiple Play instances

Tags: node.js, scala, playframework, devops, playframework-2.5

I have an application with the following characteristics:

- It's an online service offered to many companies. Each company uses a dedicated Play for Scala (Netty) application server.
- Each application server accesses a dedicated MySql database.
- In each database users' passwords are stored with MD5.
- To login, the user needs to enter on a web page the company code, the user id and the password. Alternatively, the user may go directly to its company web page where they will enter only the user id and the password.

These are my thoughts: I could implement a Node.js application server that will redirect the login to each Play application server where the user password will be validated. Am I too way off?

Comment: Wut I can offer to you is, try not to using MD5 to hash your user's password, try something like `bcryptjs` instead

Comment: Why can't all the companies use the same server?

Comment: @Robert Udah  because I don't want the companies to compete on system resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it:

1. User enters their login info into a form on the Node.js server.
2. Node.js server receives the POST request and makes an HTTP(S) request to the corresponding Play server.
3. Play server receives the request and an action verifies the login information, returning a token to the Node.js server.
4. The Node.js server responds to the original POST with a redirect to the correct Play server, including the token in the redirect URL.
5. The Play server receives the request, verifies the token and logs the user in.

Disclaimer:

There's a lot of security stuff going on here - the Node.js-Play server communication and passing the token needs to be done securely. Think: nonces, encryption, challenges, etc. I'm not an expert so I haven't made concrete suggestions about how to secure each stage, but I know the design I've given above definitely needs more work to make it properly secure. You'll want to read up on how to do this, perhaps review existing single-sign on architectures, oauth, etc, perhaps ask some specific security-related questions.

Also, using md5s for passwords is not good practice. Use a stronger hashing algorithm with a salt. See http://john.cuppi.net/migrate-from-md5-to-bcrypt-password-hashes/ for how you can migrate without disruption.